# Coldfusion autorestart

Tags: linux, redhat, coldfusion, server-crashes

Coldfusion is automatically restarting, a lot. It comes in waves, everything seems fine for a while then the server struggles for a few minutes, restarts a lot then settles down again.

I have Fusion Reactor installed, but when CF goes down FR stops logging so it's not really helping. Looking through the archived logs just shows gaps in the logs.

These are all the occourances of the phrase "Coldfusion started" today.

```
[root@server2 logs]# grep -i "Coldfusion started" server.log | grep "11/27/12"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:49:35",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:50:46",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:52:39",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:54:08",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:55:12",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:56:29",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:57:36",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:58:57",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","01:59:56",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:01:38",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:03:11",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:04:41",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:07:53",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:10:45",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:11:49",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:13:09",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:14:18",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:15:44",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:17:06",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","02:34:19",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","03:01:20",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","05:25:59",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","06:30:48",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","06:36:20",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:34:07",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:35:39",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:36:41",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:39:15",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:40:42",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:42:55",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:44:23",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:46:18",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:47:35",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:48:53",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:50:04",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:51:51",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:53:05",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:54:24",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:55:28",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:56:38",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:58:03",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","09:59:03",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","10:04:37",,"ColdFusion started"
"Information","main","11/27/12","12:04:02",,"ColdFusion started"
```

I've been looking at the live server metrics in FR on a second screen all day, the CPU, Memory and requests all seemed fine about 12 midday, then the server rebooted.

Looking at the logs for the hour between 9am and 10am (more than 15 restarts in the hour), the CPU never went over 44% usage and the Memory never exceeded 53% usage - in the recorded stats at least.

There is no JDBC tracking at the moment, so I'll add that to tracking and see if it's MySQL causing a problem, but can anyone help me narrow down the problem, what would cause Cold Fusion to auto restart, and I'm assuming the auto restart is only happening because Fusion Reactor is installed.

It's a Red Hat 5 LAMP stack running Coldfusion 9 and Fusion Reactor 4.5.2

Comment: Not really an answer, rather advice: you could try to disable the running applications one by one and see if that helps, maybe some settings as well (datasources, scheduler tasks etc.).

Comment: we only run one application, but the datasources is a good idea. I'm starting to think it's MySQL related as the CPU and RAM use is low

Comment: Is this for an internal site, or a public facing site? You may be getting attacked by a script. I would look to see why things are calm between 6:36 and 9:34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ColdFusion Administrator has a section for log files. I would look at all of them. Application.log might be particularly useful.

Also consider logging all of the incoming requests to a DB. The logging should also include the query strings.

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer my question, it was the log files that saved the day. We had external help to trace down a recursive function that was never exiting, it was found using http://www.fusion-analytics.com/fa/ which analyses log files.

Comment: Just by way of completeness - remember that there is a standard out log as in all Java appliction - found in /runtime/logs and titled "cfsuion-out.log" or *instancename*-out.log (depends on your install version and config). It has additional information regarding the Java environment. Finally, if you get hotspot errors, the log/trace for those errors (typical for a server restart) show up in the /bin directory.